Shrinkable Swing toolbar
I was tasked with implementing a toolbar that can be shrinked beyond what's necessary to display its buttons' texts. As a last resort, the buttons should hide their texts and only display their icons
Here's what my toolbar does

The first "phase" is buttons stacking themselves
If the toolbar is shrunk further, the buttons hide their texts but still store them internally
The hidden text replaces whatever tooltip was set, if it was present
Once expanded again, the buttons display both their original texts and tooltips once again
Buttons "shrink" together

Note the last bullet point. I had to uncouple shrinking logic from the width of the container, that's why I didn't override paintComponent(). Otherwise, some buttons may be still expanded while others are shrunk
Shrinkables don't allow any "partial" shrinkage. It's a limitation that I do acknowledge. Remember I didn't try to mimic paintComponent(). That said, it's not so hard to imagine an extension of Shrinkable that does support multiple shrinkage phases
There's something that bothers me though. Try adding if (isShrunk()) return as the first line of ShrinkableButton shrink() implementation. Even though that line perfectly makes sense, it breaks my toolbar by ensuring that

Button A, that has enough space for its full display, is expanded on componentResized()
Then it's shrunk because Button B did, its sibling (the toolbar propagates the shrink)
Then, this is the weird part, Button A once again executes componentResized() (as in item 1) and expands itself again.
If I don't include the check (which, again, makes so much sense I want to add it badly), item 3 never happens. That is, Button A finishes executing all of its componentResized() (whatever number of times it's invoked) before it's shrunk due to shrink propagation

Also, even though it's not necessary for the demo (that's why I didn't include it), the toolbar is not properly updated in the actual (big) production project unless I manually revalidate the toolbar on componentResized() in my ShrinkableButton
    private ComponentAdapter createShrinkingListener() {
        return new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                boolean isResized = e.getID() == ComponentEvent.COMPONENT_RESIZED;
                if (isResized) {
                    shrinkIfNecessary();
                    revalidateParent();
                }
            }

            private void revalidateParent() {
                Container parent = component.getParent();
                if (parent != null) parent.revalidate();
            }
        };
    }

I'm not sure why it happens. Even if it needs the tree lock (which may be claimed by other types in the production project), it should be released at some point. But instead of a delay, the toolbar simply doesn't update its size at all unless I trigger another resizing event (e.g. doesn't get wider if a new row is added). It's as if "automatic" revalidation (as performed in the demo) involves checking if a lock is available and abandoning the attempt if it's not. Anyway, I'm not sure, and it bother me a bit. I don't like manual revalidation
Yes, I should write javadocs. It's underway
WrapLayout is from here
package toolbar.shrinkableToolbar;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("ShrinkableToolbar Demo");

            JToolBar toolbar = createToolbar();

            JPanel mainPanel = createMainPanel();

            frame.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            frame.add(mainPanel);

            frame.pack();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private static JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(new Color(177, 216, 137));
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 200));
        return panel;
    }

    private static JToolBar createToolbar() {
        Icon iconOne = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");
        Icon iconTwo = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.questionIcon");
        Icon iconThree = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon");
        String buttonText = "long long long text button";
        ShrinkableButton buttonOne = new ShrinkableButton("Button One: " + buttonText, iconOne);
        buttonOne.setToolTipText("Button One business tooltip");
        ShrinkableButton buttonTwo = new ShrinkableButton("Button Two: " + buttonText, iconTwo);
        buttonTwo.setToolTipText("Button Two business tooltip");
        ShrinkableButton buttonThree = new ShrinkableButton("Button Three: " + buttonText, iconThree);
        buttonThree.setToolTipText("Button Three business tooltip");
        ShrinkableToolbar toolbar = new ShrinkableToolbar();
        FlowLayout layout = new WrapLayout();
        toolbar.setLayout(layout);
        toolbar.add(buttonOne);
        toolbar.add(buttonTwo);
        toolbar.add(buttonThree);
        return toolbar;
    }
}

package toolbar.shrinkableToolbar;

public interface PublishingShrinkable extends Shrinkable {
    void addShrinkListener(ShrinkListener listener);
    void removeShrinkListener(ShrinkListener listener);
}

package toolbar.shrinkableToolbar;

public interface Shrinkable {
    void shrink();
    boolean isShrunk();
}

package toolbar.shrinkableToolbar;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.HierarchyEvent;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

public class ShrinkableButton extends ShrinkableComponent<JButton> {
    private static final String STORED_TEXT_KEY = "storedText";
    private static final String STORED_TOOLTIP_KEY = "storedTooltip";
    private final List<ShrinkListener> shrinkListeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    public ShrinkableButton(String text, Icon icon) {
        super(new JButton(text, icon));
        component.setFocusPainted(false);
        component.addHierarchyListener(this::onHierarchyChanged);
        setText(text);
        if (icon != null) component.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight()));
    }

    public void setToolTipText(String text) {
        component.putClientProperty(STORED_TOOLTIP_KEY, text);
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        component.putClientProperty(STORED_TEXT_KEY, text);
        shrinkIfNecessary();
    }

    public void addShrinkListener(ShrinkListener listener) {
        shrinkListeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeShrinkListener(ShrinkListener listener) {
        shrinkListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    private void onHierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent event) {
        boolean isParentAdded = (event.getChangeFlags() & HierarchyEvent.PARENT_CHANGED) != 0;
        if (isParentAdded) component.getParent().addComponentListener(createShrinkingListener());
    }

    private ComponentAdapter createShrinkingListener() {
        return new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                boolean isResized = e.getID() == ComponentEvent.COMPONENT_RESIZED;
                if (isResized) shrinkIfNecessary();
            }
        };
    }

    private void shrinkIfNecessary() {
        if (shouldShrink()) shrink();
        else expand();
    }

    private boolean shouldShrink() {
        if (component.getIcon() == null) return false;
        boolean shouldShrink = getFullWidth() >= getAvailableWidth();
        return shouldShrink;
    }

    private int getFullWidth() {
        Insets buttonInsets = component.getInsets();
        int iconWidth = component.getIcon().getIconWidth();
        String originalText = getStoredText();
        int textWidth = component.getFontMetrics(component.getFont()).stringWidth(originalText);
        return buttonInsets.left + iconWidth + component.getIconTextGap() + textWidth + buttonInsets.right;
    }

    private int getAvailableWidth() {
        Container parent = component.getParent();
        return Optional.ofNullable(parent)
                .map(Component::getWidth)
                .orElse(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    @Override
    public void shrink() {
        component.setText("");
        component.setToolTipText(getStoredText());
        fireShrinkEvent();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isShrunk() {
        return component == null || component.getText() == null || component.getText().isEmpty();
    }

    private void fireShrinkEvent() {
        ShrinkEvent event = new ShrinkEvent(this);
        for (ShrinkListener listener : shrinkListeners)
            listener.onShrink(event);
    }

    private void expand() {
        component.setText(getStoredText());
        component.setToolTipText(getStoredToolTipText());
    }

    private String getStoredText() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(component.getClientProperty(STORED_TEXT_KEY))
                .filter(String.class::isInstance)
                .map(String.class::cast)
                .orElse(null);
    }

    private String getStoredToolTipText() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(component.getClientProperty(STORED_TOOLTIP_KEY))
                .filter(String.class::isInstance)
                .map(String.class::cast)
                .orElse(null);
    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener l) {
        component.addActionListener(l);
    }

    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener l) {
        component.removeActionListener(l);
    }
}

package toolbar.shrinkableToolbar;

import java.awt.*;

public abstract class ShrinkableComponent<T extends Component> implements PublishingShrinkable {
    protected final T component;

    protected ShrinkableComponent(T component) {
        this.component = component;
    }

    public T getComponent() {
        return component;
    }
}

package toolbar.shrinkableToolbar;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

public class ShrinkableToolbar extends JToolBar {
    private final List<ShrinkableComponent<?>> shrinkableComponents = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    public ShrinkableToolbar() {
        FlowLayout layout = new WrapLayout();
        setLayout(layout);
        setFloatable(false);
        setRollover(true);
        setOpaque(false);
    }

    public <T extends Component> Component add(ShrinkableComponent<T> shrinkableComponent) {
        shrinkableComponent.addShrinkListener(this::shrinkAll);
        shrinkableComponents.add(shrinkableComponent);
        return super.add(shrinkableComponent.getComponent());
    }

    private void shrinkAll(ShrinkEvent shrinkEvent) {
        for (ShrinkableComponent<?> shrinkableComponent : shrinkableComponents) {
            if (shrinkableComponent.isShrunk()) continue;
            shrinkableComponent.shrink();
        }
    }
}

package toolbar.shrinkableToolbar;

import publishingButtonGroup.SourcedEvent;

// I don't care about the source in this case so I don't bother with specifying a more precise source type
public class ShrinkEvent extends SourcedEvent<Object> {
    public ShrinkEvent(Object source) {
        super(source);
    }
}

package toolbar.shrinkableToolbar;

public interface ShrinkListener {
    void onShrink(ShrinkEvent event);
}

// it may be redundant in for the purposes of this demo, but for some other (existing in the codebase) events it is necessary to call non-Object methods on the source
public abstract class SourcedEvent<S> {
    protected final S source;

    protected SourcedEvent(S source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public S getSource() {
        return source;
    }
}




